# Proof on why regular graphs have an all-one eigenvector?

Tags: connectedness

I came across the theorem : A connected graph is regular if and only if the all-one vector is an eigenvector of A. I am not sure on how to prove every connected regular graph has an all-one eigenvector.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Applying $A$ to the all-one vector produces a vector with the vertex degrees as entries. This is a multiple of the all-one vector (i.e., all entries are equal) iff the graph is regular.